# Change words in a Tikz picture every page

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, environments

I'd like to create a template, as below. But I'd like to make it so that I can have multiple pages of the same layout and be able to easily replace "Header 1" and "Header 2" with different words each time.

[image]

I am able to make the gray boxes and place the words using the code below. Right now I have them in as a header so that it'll easily be place on each page.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, fill]
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=9cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=0cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=0cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=9.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont Header 1};
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont Header 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to define a new environment with a tikz picture so that I can just define that environment and change the words as needed without having to individually place the headers/words each time.

Comment: Why not use `\newcommand{\myheadertext}{Insert here}` and then you simply change its value.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. How do I implement that in to the tikzpicture code? And how would I be able to define multiple headertexts?

Comment: If I well understood you want to change the header text in a simple way. So you can define a variable to save the header text and you use it inside the tikz environment. For example, `\selectfont\myheadertext`. So when you redefine it and use the environment again you'll obtain another output.

Comment: Ahh yes that works. I forgot about \renewcommand to change the words each new page.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want anything else in tikzpicture environment then you could define

```
\newcommand\PageHeader[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, fill]
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=9cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=0cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=0cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=9.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont #1};
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

and then use something like `\PageHeader{Header 1}{Header 2}` on each page.

If you would also like to able to add something inside the tikzpicture environment use:

```
\newenvironment{PageHeader}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, fill]
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=9cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=8.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \path [fill=lightgray]
            ([yshift=0cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=0cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=9.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont #1};
        \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=west,
              xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm] at (current page.west)
              {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont #2};%
    }{\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Now you can write something like this:

```
\begin{PageHeader}{Header 1}{Header 2}
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
\end{PageHeader}
```